# Modularity and link communities trade-off in complex networks

Tags: modularity, complex-networks

I just finished reading about techniques to detect communities. One thing which is bothering me is that is there a way or is there some network in which we can detect communities using modularity optimization method but not using link communities method ? I was able to find a network which works  the other way round (link community method works, but modularity optimization doesn't ). Essentially, what is the flaw in the using links similarities to find communities and in which cases in modularity more preferable.

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you call *link communities*? And also maybe give the example your refer to in your last sentence.

Comment: I am referring to this paper . http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v466/n7307/full/nature09182.html.                So now i found out networks where modularity optimization does not work, essentially overlapping and nested communities.  By "link community" i mean a community which can be detected using the link similarities instead of modularity which focuses on nodes. Now I want a network structure where the link community detection method fails but the modularity optimization technique works.

Comment: If the link community method can detect overlapping (node) communities, then it's more general than (regular) modularity-based method. So, in theory, it can detect communities even if they're not overlapping. This means it should perform well when modularity optimization does, whereas the contrary is not necessary true.
I've got a question, however: how do you determine if a method did detect a community structure? What's your criterion?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest flaw of the link-based methods are the time complexity which is crucial in large scale networks.

A sample of modularity optimization is the "Newman"'s fast algorithm.

It starts with each node in a separate community and in each step it merges the 2 communities which make the better growth in modularity factor.

You can use the modularity metric of your choice.

The algorithm terminates when the modularity cannot become any better.